# Using nftables to drop UDP packets on a random basis

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nftables

I have an iptables rule that I use to drop UDP packets on a random basis. I'm trying to convert this to nftables, but I'm likely making a syntax error, because nftables complains that the "dport" argument is unexpected.

Here's my iptables rule: `iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10 -p udp --destination-port 2020 -i eth0 -j DROP`

I tried using `iptables-translate` but I get the same rule back:

```
$ iptables-translate -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10 -p udp  --destination-port 2020 -i eth0  -j DROP
nft # -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10 -p udp --destination-port 2020 -i eth0 -j DROP
```

I tried to create my own nftables table, chain and rule using:

```
$ sudo nft add table ip filter
$ sudo nft add chain ip filter mychain
```

But when I try to use the rule, I get the error that `dport` is unexpected:

```
$ sudo nft add rule ip filter mychain input udp dport 2020 drop
Error: syntax error, unexpected dport, expecting end of file or newline or semicolon
add rule ip filter mychain input udp dport 2020 drop
                                     ^^^^^
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why can't `iptables-translate` translate this rule?

Comment: The problem you have and the title don't match. Before asking this question, you MUST read documentation. Wiki: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page . More specifically: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains . Then for the title: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Math_operations . iptables-translate doesn't offer any guarantee it will work. Here it didn't, because nobody took care of making it translate correctly  `-m statistic`. see LIMITATIONS: https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-translate.8#LIMITATIONS

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/971826/how-to-drop-packets-based-on-a-probability-with-nftables